# Error in predicate for LIKE

Tags: java, prepared-statement, pervasive-sql

```
int sixteen = 16;
String full="%"+sixteen+"%";
conn = PervasiveUtil.loadDriver();
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT BKAR_INV_SONUM "
                           + " FROM BKARINV "
                           + " WHERE BKAR_INV_SONUM > 150000 "
                           + " AND BKAR_INV_SONUM LIKE ?"
                           + " ORDER BY BKAR_INV_SONUM DESC");
stmt.setString(1, full);
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

This code produced an error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Error in predicate: BKAR_INV_SONUM LIKE ?
```

BKAR_INV_SONUM type is int in Database. Does that affect my prepare statement? Should I use `setInt()` instead of `setString()`?

Comment: In most TSQL impl's I'm aware of, I'm pretty sure `LIKE` is a string operator.  You'd need to cast `BKAR_INV_SONUM` to a varchar/nvarchar/some other character type before using a LIKE.  Look up type casting for your db.

Comment: ` CONVERT(BKAR_INV_SONUM, SQL_VARCHAR) LIKE ?`

Comment: It work. Thanks Taylor, and Joop Eggen.